# Less Loop basically downgrades performance?

Tags: css, loops, less

I made this less loop to generate css code needed to a specific task.
(included at bottom of page).
Is it safe to say that writing less-loops reduce development time but also generates unnecessary code styles?
I can see a lot of benefits of using this technique but none of them include performance optimization aspects.

```
    @items : 12;
@color-base : red;
@slice : 30deg;
.looop (@i) when (@i>0){
  .looop(@i - 1);
  li:nth-child(@{i}){
    transform: rotate((@i*@slice)-30) skewY(-2*@slice);
    .text {
      background  : spin(@color-base, 30);
    }
  }
}
.looop(@items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize it a bit:

```
@items : 12;
@excluded-items: 1, 2, 5;
@color-base : red;
@slice : 30deg;

.looop (@i) when (@i>0) {
  .looop(@i - 1);

  li:nth-child(@{i}){
    transform: rotate((@i*@slice)-30) skewY(-2*@slice);
  }
}

.looop(@items);

li {
  .text {
      background  : spin(@color-base, 30);
    }
}
```